# наложение картинки на видео в ffmpeg

Tags: изображения, видео, ffmpeg

У меня есть видео input.mp4 и картинка logo.png. Мне нужно наложить логотип на видео с 5 по 15 секунду. И картинка должна быть в левом верхнем углу с отступом по 30 пикселей. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать в ffmpeg.

Comment: Типа иконки канала на ютубе) Я думаю тут недостаточно тегов или описания, в видеопоток нужно вставить логотип или в какой-то форме?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Читайте про [фильтры](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) и обработку [выражений](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation). В частности, вам нужен фильтр [оверлей](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1). Отмечу, что применение фильтров без перекодирования видео невозможно.

Дальше нужно немного фантазии по комбинации ограниченного набора фильтров для получения требуемого эффекта: сначала лого должно появиться в какой-то момент времени, а потом исчезнуть. Сделать этом можно при помощи двух фильтров [fade](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fade): первый будет включать картинку, а второй выключать. При помощи него же можно сделать и плавно появление/исчезновение.

Следующим шагом будет - нарисовать схему фильтра на бумаге, карандашом или ручкой, например как [тут](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction).

В вашем случае схема может быть такая:

```
[0:v] ------------------------> overlay --> output
                                   ^
                                   |
[1:v] --> fade[in] --> fade[out] --+
```

Ну а реализация такой:

```
ffmpeg -i $video -framerate 30000/1001 -loop 1 -i $logo -filter_complex "[1:v] fade=st=5:n=1:alpha=1, fade=out:st=10:n=1:alpha=1 [logo]; [0:v][logo] overlay=10:10" -y out.mkv
```

в данном примере лого будет включено с 5 (`st=5` у первого fade) по 10 (`st=10` у второго fade) секунду и появится мгновенно (`n=1`). Для плавного появления исчезновения поиграйтесь с параметром `n` - длительность эффекта в фреймах или замените его на `d=XXX` - длительность эффекта в секундах (дроби позволены).