# Добавление текста в видео в ffmpeg

Tags: видео, ffmpeg, text

Есть видео файл video.mp4. В него нужно добавить текст с указанием шрифта и цвета в координатах 15, 400. Подскажите как это сделать в ffmpeg?

Answer (score 3):

Первое предложение [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533141/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE-%D0%B2-ffmpeg/533217#533217).

В вашем конкретном случае речь о фильтре [drawtext](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1).